# Как установить модуль xgboost на анаконду?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pip, anaconda

Возникла проблема - не удается установить XGBOOST на Анаконду 5.1.0 
Путь первый - через cmd обновлял pip, устанавливал xgboost, но на проверке (import xgboost) выдавалась ошибка.

Путь второй, в блокноте применял код найденный в другом вопросе:

```
import subprocess
import sys

package = 'xgboost'
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
```

и он выдает такую ошибку:

```
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-46597166ab7e> in <module>()
  3 
  4 package = 'xgboost'
----> 5 subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])

C:\Conda\lib\subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
289         if cmd is None:
290             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 291         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
292     return 0
293 

CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Conda\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 
'install', 'xgboost']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Подскажите, какие еще есть варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло

```
 conda install py-xgboost
```

в командной строке